# Spring cache constant as a key

Tags: spring-cache

As part of my code I have a method with empty parameters. For e..g,

```
public MasterData fetchMasterData() {
// DO something.
}
```

I want to add a @Cacheable with key as 'masterdata'. I tried the following, but it looks for a bean named 'masterdata'.
I tried `@Cacheable(cache="master", key="masterdata")`

If I leave the key attribute, I know it takes as empty key. But I want to explicitly give a constant as key.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `key` attribute is a [SpEL expression](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#expressions) so if you want the key to be `masterdata` you would write something like this

```
@Cacheable(cache="master", key="'masterdata'")
public MasterData fetchMasterData() { ... }
```